# Rails server starts but AR Connection not established for reading role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pg

A confusion with the `pg` gem compiled against some previous version of homebrew, leading to the reinstallation of postgresql, led to uninstalling and reinstalling the pg gem.
`gem uninstall pg   gem install pg`

Subsequently, the rails console and server can be activated, and while the former can be used, the server returns an error when previously this had never been seen.  Needless to say, nothing else changed in the application in the meantime.

```
Processing by HomeController#hello as HTML
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (Allocations: 3461)

ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (No connection pool for 'ActiveRecord::Base' found for the 'reading' role.):
```

pointing to an issue with `config/database.yml`
There, the default suggestion fro Rails 7 indicates:

```
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
```

but `/usr/local` is an empty directory and  the install command with those options fails

```
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.
```

the simple gem install command yields:

```
gem install pg
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
Successfully installed pg-1.4.3
Parsing documentation for pg-1.4.3
Installing ri documentation for pg-1.4.3
Done installing documentation for pg after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
```

database.yml  is configured by stock rails installation:

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  primary:
    <<: *default
    database: mrt_development
    username: deploy_root
    password: [...]
  primary_replica:
    <<: *default
    database: mrkt_test
    username: deploy_readonly
    password: password
    replica: true
```

The [rails guide][1] provides no indications as to 'reading' roles.

What should be done to get a proper connection running?
[1]: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling

**Update**
Interesting behaviour observed: a deployment has led to the same error being generated on the remote server.

Comment: Try this `pool:  <%= (ENV["RAILS_MAX_THREADS"] || 5) * 2 %>`

Comment: No, that does not change anything.  I also tried straight out `pool: 5` leading to the same result

Comment: Have you set the database url?

Comment: No, I have not.  This is not a task I usually run.  Subsequently, I did a fresh reinstall of the development machine.  All basic tasks runs as expected up to the creation of a new application and its database.  However, when carting over the folder for the application this error, creating the database (succeeds), `rails s` launches and I get the same error.  Thus, clearly something got altered but what.  How can your suggestion be investigated?

Comment: You do seem to be on the right track as `bundle exec echo $DATABASE_URL` yields nil.  Further note: `rails c`  launches and queries the database correctly.

Comment: I am starting to perceive that this may be a problem with the primary and replica definitions.  and the original environment variables were overwritten by, what I thought was an unrelated process of `brew install ffmpeg` overwriting environment variables (which done rarely just slips out of human memory).